# WebStorm importing lodash/fp/xxx

Tags: functional-programming, lodash, webstorm

Do you know whether it's possible to setup WebStorm in the way it will import functions from *functional programming (FP) module* (`lodash/fp/xxx`)?

After reading ["Why using `_.chain` is a mistake."](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba) I wrote few functions using `flow` function such as that in the example:

```
import map from "lodash/fp/map";
import flatten from "lodash/fp/flatten";
import sortBy from "lodash/fp/sortBy";
import flow from "lodash/fp/flow";
flow(
  map(x => [x, x*2]), 
  flatten, 
  sortBy(x => x)
)([1, 2, 3]);
```

Unfortunately, I don't see option to import those functions from `lodash/fp` package in the context menu in WebStorm. Is there an option to enable them somehow?

Comment: unfortunately `node_modules/lodash/fp/map.js` doesn't export `map` function (or, actually, it does, but in a dynamic way that can only be resolved in runtime). That's why the IDE doesn't suggest importing from this file. This is true for all functions from `fp` package - they all are exported via `convert('func', require('../func'))`

Comment: It's possible to install typescript hints to project (Settings > Javascript > Libraries), but webstorm doesn't seem to use them, and stilt refers to js file. 
Anybody knows how it should work?